# python plotly treemap: Add images to labels

Tags: python, pandas, image, plotly, treemap

I am trying to add logos to the labels in a treemap in Python Plotly express.

I would like to replace text labels with logo PNG images.

I would like the pictures to fit to the relative areas. Also for the treemap to be interactive.
So the images will resize and move relative to the area. Hence I am trying to add them to the labels and not overlaying them on to the figure.

Below is the minimal reproducible code.
*In the origin code the treemap has more attributes, the images are different for each skill and images stored locally*.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px

# Get sample image for site
img_url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/Python-logo-notext.svg/1200px-Python-logo-notext.svg.png"
img = Image.open(urlopen(img_url))

# Create data frame 
data = {'skills' : ['c#', 'pyhton', 'r', 'sas', 'sql'],
        'count' : [0, 19, 14, 7, 40],}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['groups'] = 'Languages'
df['images'] = img 

# Create treemap 
fig = px.treemap(df, path=[px.Constant("all"),'groups','skills'], values='count', labels= "images",)

fig.update_traces(root_color="lightgrey")
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))

# Update labels to images
fig.update_traces(labels = df["images"], selector=dict(type='treemap'))

fig.show()
```

Can anyone show me where I am going wrong please?